# Resolving Error while installing pinot using mvn clean install

Tags: maven, installation, pinot

I am trying to install pinot after downloading the code from this repository.

I am executing via admin mode on win 7 64 bit the following command

`mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pbin-dist`

On github it was suggested to add following additional parameters to the above command

`-Dcheckstyle.skip  -Drat.numUnapprovedLicenses=1000`

However, the above completed command read as

`mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pbin-dist  -Dcheckstyle.skip  -Drat.numUnapprovedLicenses=1000`

creates infinite loop of recompiling the files

The output is placed at github with the url
[text](https://github.com/apache/pinot/issues/11836)

Comment: There is a hint about: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-maven-plugin:2.28.
0:check (default) on project pinot-spi: The following files had format violation` which is the problem.... first make a `spotless:applay` and rerun...

Comment: Can please tell the specific command that needs to be changed/editied. ?